# How to validate multiple fields at the same time using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have created a form that validates using JQuery and JavaScript. The only problem is, would be that it validates one field at a time. So the user has to correct the first field first and then press submit again to see if the next field is valid.

What I would like to to do, is have the JQuery validate the whole form after pressing submit and show all the applicable error messages.

**Here is My JS:**

```
function validateUserName()
{
    var u = document.forms["NewUser"]["user"].value
    var uLength = u.length;
    var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores
    if (u == null || u == "")
    {

        $("#ErrorUser").text("You Left the Username field Emptyyy");
        return false;
    }
    else if (uLength < 4 || uLength > 11)
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username must be between 4 and 11 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else if (illegalChars.test(u))
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username contains illegal charectors men!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function validatePassword()
{
    var p = document.forms["NewUser"]["pwd"].value
    var cP = document.forms["NewUser"]["confirmPwd"].value
    var pLength = p.length;
    if (p == null || p == "")
    {
        $("#ErrorPassword1").text("You left the password field empty");
        return false;
    }
    else if (pLength < 6 || pLength > 20)
    {
        $("#ErrorPassword1").text("Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters in length");
        return false;
    }
    else if (p != cP)
    {
        $("#ErrorPassword1").text("Th passwords do not match!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function validateEmail()
{
    var e = document.forms["NewUser"]["email"].value
    var eLength = e.length;
    var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/;

    if (eLength == "" || eLength == null)
    {

        $("#ErrorEmail").text("You left the email field blank!");
        return false;
    }
    else if (e.match(illegalChars))
    {

        $("#ErrorEmail").text("ILEGAL CHARECTORS DETECTED EXTERMINATE");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function validateFirstName()
{
    var f = document.forms["NewUser"]["fName"].value;
    var fLength = f.length;
    var illegalChars = /\W/;

    if (fLength > 20)
    {
        $("#ErrorFname").text("First Name has a max of 20 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else if (illegalChars.test(f))
    {
        $("#ErrorFname").text("Numbers,letter and underscores in first name only");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }


}

function validateLastName()
{
    var l = document.forms["NewUser"]["lName"].value;
    var lLength = l.length;
    var illegalChars = /\W/;

    if (lLength > 100)
    {
        $("#ErrorLname").text("Last Name has a max of 100 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else if (illegalChars.test(f))
    {
        $("#ErrorLname").text("Numbers,letter and underscores in last name only");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }


}

function validateForm()
{
    valid = true;
    //call username function
    valid = valid && validateUserName();

    //call password function
    valid = valid && validatePassword();

    //call email function
    valid = valid && validateEmail();

    //call first name function
    valid = valid && validateFirstName();

    //call first name function
    valid = valid && validateLastName();

    return valid;
}
```

**And here is my submit form code:**

```
$('#your-form').submit(validateForm);
```

Comment: have you considered using jquery validate plugin `-->` http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/

Comment: make all your if conditions independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `true` or `false` return a string containing the error and an empty string if no error was found.

Then `validateForm` could be something like

```
function validateForm()
{
    error = "";
    //call username function
    error += "\n"+validateUserName();

    //call password function
    error += "\n"+validatePassword();
    ...
    if(error === ""){
        return true;
    }
    $("#ErrorLname").text(error);
    return false;
}
```

#### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzes/)

Comment: Awesome, seems to be working. Would just like to know, what the ellipsis means? (Or is that where I put the rest of the validator functions?)

Comment: Rest of the validator functions according to your form structure. I've added a fiddle on jsfiddle.net . If this solved your issue, please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: This is a new account, so I have to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer, will do so when the time is up :).

Comment: I am having a new problem now, the form won't submit after I have corrected the values?

Comment: @user2396852 in my fiddle example I don't submit, I just alert and return false anyway (for it to work well in a fiddle). In the fiddle instead of alerting "YAY" you need to `return true;`

Comment: Like this?
    if(error === ""){
        return true;
    }
 else{
  return false;
 }

Comment: Yeah, but in the `}else{` part you should also put the error message in the correct place like in the fiddle.

Comment: It is still not working, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87PVq/

(It is now submiting regardless)

Comment: @user2396852 you did not change your functions like "validateUserName" to return a string, you're still returning true/false, check my example carefully.

Comment: @BejaminGruenBaum I have updated the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87PVq/1/

and done what you said but it is still not working?

Comment: @user2396852 You need to _return_ the _error_ (and not update the `.text`!) in each method or empty string if no such error exists. There is no point in returning `"--"` or such.

Comment: Yes. This is getting too chatty for an SO question, If you have any other questions, please ask them in another question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access all the fields and check if the field is valid r not. If the field is valid skip it, otherwise put the field in an array. When all the fields have been checked, then display the error fields from the array all at one time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var validate;
function validateUserName()
{
       validate = true;
        var u = document.forms["NewUser"]["user"].value
        var uLength = u.length;
        var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores
        if (u == null || u == "")
        {
            $("#ErrorUser").text("You Left the Username field Emptyyy");
            validate     = false;
        }
        else if (uLength <4 || uLength > 11)
        {
            $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username must be between 4 and 11 characters");
            validate     = false;
        }
        else if (illegalChars.test(u)) 
        {
            $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username contains illegal charectors men!");
            validate     = false;
        }

}

    function validatePassword()
    {
        var p = document.forms["NewUser"]["pwd"].value
        var cP = document.forms["NewUser"]["confirmPwd"].value
        var pLength = p.length;
        if (p == null || p == "")
        {
            $("#ErrorPassword1").text("You left the password field empty");
           validate     = false;
        }
        else if (pLength < 6 || pLength > 20)
        {
            $("#ErrorPassword1").text("Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters in length");
            validate     = false;
        }
        else if (p != cP)
        {
            $("#ErrorPassword1").text("Th passwords do not match!");
            validate     = false;
        }

    }

    function validateEmail()
    {
        var e = document.forms["NewUser"]["email"].value
        var eLength = e.length;
        var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
        var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;

        if (eLength == "" || eLength == null) 
        {

            $("#ErrorEmail").text("You left the email field blank!");
            validate     = false;
        } 
        else if (e.match(illegalChars)) 
        {

            $("#ErrorEmail").text("ILEGAL CHARECTORS DETECTED EXTERMINATE");
           validate     = false;
        } 

    }
    function validateFirstName()
    {
        var f = document.forms["NewUser"]["fName"].value;
        var fLength = f.length;
        var illegalChars = /\W/;

        if(fLength > 20)
        {
            $("#ErrorFname").text("First Name has a max of 20 characters");
            validate     = false;
        }
        else if (illegalChars.test(f))
        {
            $("#ErrorFname").text("Numbers,letter and underscores in first name only");
            validate     = false;
        }



    }

    function validateLastName()
    {
        var l = document.forms["NewUser"]["lName"].value;
        var lLength = l.length;
        var illegalChars = /\W/;

        if(lLength > 100)
        {
            $("#ErrorLname").text("Last Name has a max of 100 characters");
           validate     = false;
        }
        else if (illegalChars.test(f))
        {
            $("#ErrorLname").text("Numbers,letter and underscores in last name only");
            validate     = false;
        }

    }

function validateForm()   
{


     validateUserName();  
     validatePassword();    
     validateEmail();
     validateFirstName();
     validateLastName();

    return validate;
}
```